# Using AwsCustomResource for a large number of resources?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I need a component for creating a large number of CodeCommit users. CloudFormation doesn't support adding a public SSH key for an IAM user, so I have to create my own. CDK comes with `AwsCustomResource`, which does the heavy lifting of creating the Lambda that handles the required CloudFormation events. In other words, my code would be something like:

```
import { User } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-iam';
import { AwsCustomResource } from 'aws-cdk-lib/custom-resources';
import { Construct } from 'constructs';

export interface CodeCommitUserProps {
  userName: string;
  emailAddress: string;
  sshPublicKey: string;
}

export class CodeCommitUser extends Construct {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: CodeCommitUserProps) {
    super(scope, id);
      
    const user = new User(this, 'codecommit-' + props.userName, {
      userName: 'codecommit-' + props.userName,
      path: '/git/users'
    });
  }

  const custom = new AwsCustomResource(this, ... );
}
```

Now if I call `new CodeCommitUser(...)` a few hundred times, I would assume that there will be one CloudFormation event Lambda per user, even if all of them are identical. Is there a way to reuse the Lambdas created by `AwsCustomResource` if I need multiple copies of the custom resource?

Answer (score 2):

> I would assume that there will be one CloudFormation event Lambda per user, even if all of them are identical.

Actually, no.  CDK creates a single lambda function, no matter how many times `CodeCommitUser` is instantiated.  How does CDK manage this?  Under the hood, CDK uses a [SingletonFunction](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda.SingletonFunction.html) for the `AWSCustomResource` provider (see the [github source](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/50637e08590c2051d9a1e446ee7ded47e85d02b3/packages/%40aws-cdk/custom-resources/lib/aws-custom-resource/aws-custom-resource.ts#L360)).  Singleton Functions are guaranteed to be added to the stack *"once and only once, irrespective of how many times the construct is declared to be part of the stack"*

> Is there a way to reuse the Lambdas created by AwsCustomResource if I need multiple copies of the custom resource?

Again, reuse happens automagically.  You can prove this to yourself by `cdk synth`-ing the stack with multiple `CodeCommitUser`s defined.  Then look in the `cdk.out` directory for the outputted CloudFormation template.  The template have only one `AWS::Lambda::Function` resource defined (assuming your app doesn't use lambdas elsewhere).

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom resource lambda and deploy it in a separate template. Then you can call on it from what ever template you want.
You can call this resource as many times you want from a single template.
You can either send a list of users in one go, or create a resource for each user (probably not ideal if you talking hundreds).